# Finding correct Selenium web element based on child element nesting

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I have two buttons that need to be clicked, but sometimes one of them will not be there. Calling them buttons '1' and '2'. Sometimes, button 1 has the path of button 2 if button 2 isn't on the page. Buttons 1 and 2 have different child elements. Button 1 has a  tag wrapping a

tag while Button 2 ONLY has a  tag as a child element. So I need a way of determining which is which based on the child elements, because the classes and other css elements are the same.

I read about selenium axes but don't understand how they would work in this context.

```
Button 1 XPath: "//*[@id='main-content']/section[3]/div[2]/button" // has child element <span><p>content here<\p><\span>

Button 2 XPath: "//*[@id='main-content']/section[4]/div[2]/button" // has child element <span>content here<\span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to distinguish between "Button 1" and "Button 2" based on the child elements within the buttons using Selenium by looking at the child elements and their attributes.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your_website_url_here")
try:
    button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/section[3]/div[2]/button")

    if button1.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span/p"):
        print("Button 1 clicked")
        button1.click()
    else:
        button2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/section[4]/div[2]/button")
        print("Button 2 clicked")
        button2.click()

except NoSuchElementException as e:
    # Handle the exception if the element is not found
    print("Element not found. Exception message:", e)


driver.quit()
```

Comment: The code you provided may be should work, but there's a minor issue with your exception handling. You should specify the specific exception you want to catch, which is NoSuchElementException in this case.

Comment: @SHUBHAMSHEDGE sure there is a way. I have modified the code for you.